# github pages site doesn't work in some browsers

Tags: google-chrome, github, github-pages

I made github pages site with a custom domain.
It runs in Tor and Safari but I get "This site can’t be reached" message trying to run it in Chrome and some other browsers, what could be wrong?
The repository is public, cache is cleaned.

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file where my domain name was pointed to localhost
the file was changed probably probably due to my attempts to host the site on a laptop